# Chrome browsers crashed and unable to restore

Tags: google-chrome

my chrome browsers crashed and I had a lot of tabs open, im unable to restore them. can someone please help?!

Answer (score 0):

You best bet it to go into your browsing history and open a new tab for each site in your history that you want to reopen.